# Etherscan API no decimals separator

Tags: erc-20, external-api, api-design

I am using Etherscan API to retrieve certain erc20 token balance on given ETH address and get a number like 62910000000 without decimals separator. In fact the proper balance is 6291000.0000. How to fix it? Or maybe how can I display it in a correct way?

Answer (score 2):

Most ERC20 tokens should follow the pattern of using 18 decimal places for their token. If your token is using a special value, you can either hard code that, or use other APIs to retrieve that [`decimals` value](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md#decimals) for the token.

The Etherscan API is returning you the value without that in consideration, but all you really need to do is divide that number by 10<sup>18</sup> (or add the decimal place in the right spot using string manipulation).

For example [this account](https://etherscan.io/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52?a=0x16d267f8f77617d327af137d2c9137cfd140df86) has 418.98 in BNB.

The [api query](https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52&address=0x16d267f8f77617d327af137d2c9137cfd140df86&tag=latest&apikey=YourApiKeyToken) returns `"418940000000000000000"`.

If you divide by 10<sup>18</sup> you will get the "real" token balance. Note that you will need to use some sort of ["big number" library](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/) to do this kind of math, or as I mentioned, string manipulation:

```
> a.slice(0,a.length - 18) + "." + a.slice(a.length - 18, a.length)
"418.940000000000000000"
```