# Etherscan API Get Balance - Decimals Not Showing In Response

Tags: ether, etherscan, balances, external-api, explorer-api

## Expected

Use the *[Etherscan API](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts)* to make a `GET` request for an ETH address' balance in order to receive a response providing the Ether token quantity representing all decimal places.

## Observed

The response provides the Ether token quantity without representing any decimal places.

**Request: Etherscan Get Ether Balance for a single Address**

`http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0x8a27D05e97A156E93D42a6d3afB5c2154ebb9cB5&tag=latest&apikey={YOUR_API_KEY_HERE}`

*Note: I chose a random ETH address above. This is not my ETH address.*

**Response**

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "message": "OK",
    "result": "86354095000000000"
}
```

**Balance From Etherscan UX**

The balance from the Etherscan UX indicates that decimal places are included in the Ether balance. However, the API response does not provide any information regarding decimal formatting.

*[0.086354095 Ether](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8a27D05e97A156E93D42a6d3afB5c2154ebb9cB5)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `result` from the Etherscan `GET` request's response must be divided by 10<sup>18</sup>.

As *[answered](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/67608/7700)* in this post regarding *ERC20* tokens decimal places, *"Most ERC20 tokens should follow the pattern of using 18 decimal places for their token."*

This applies to Ether itself. Therefore, the `result` response of `86354095000000000` is equal to *0.086354095* Ether.

*(86354095000000000/(10<sup>18</sup>)) = 0.086354095*

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously in this example you need to do the formatting by your self. The presented return value is in wei, you can convert it into eth by using `web3` library:

`web3.utils.fromWei('86354095000000000', 'ether');`

This will return a 0.086354095 value.